# get request Task timed out in Lambda using Python

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, python-requests, httprequest

I'm new to AWS and Python.
I'm trying to get the results of HTTP requests through Lambda.
I attached the layer which includes requests library.

Here is the problem:

Runtime:Python 3.7

```
import requests
# import urllib.request *already tried
# from botocore.vendored import requests *already tried

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        params = (
        ('hoge', 'fuga'),
        ('piyo', 'pipiyo')
    )

    print('API start')
    response = requests.get('https://sample.com', params=params)
    if response is None:
        print('no response')
    print(response)

# get the first num of status code
    status = response.status_code
    print(status)
    status_head = status[1]
    output = response.json()
    print(output)

# get the result and error message from body
    json_data = json.load(output)
    result = json_data["result"]
    error = json_data["error"]
    print(result)
    print(error)
    return result
```

What I get is

```
Response:
{
  "errorMessage": "2020-06-24T05:50:43.309Z 035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds"
}

Request ID:
"035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885"

Function Logs:
START RequestId: 035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885 Version: $LATEST
API start
END RequestId: 035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885
REPORT RequestId: 035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885  Duration: 60058.03 ms   Billed Duration: 60000 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 73 MB  Init Duration: 789.24 ms    
2020-06-24T05:50:43.309Z 035e9470-c067-40bb-adc3-7c5b1f72f885 Task timed out after 60.06 seconds
```

When I send this request from Talend API Tester, the response returns right.

Do I have to change parameters of test events? Does that matter?
Current content is

```
{
  "key1": "value1",
  "key2": "value2"
}
```

What am I missing here? Please tell me if I have to add more info.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What happens when you run this code locally (provided you can access the url locally)? Usually when something times out I immediately think of a network issue. By default the security groups (these are basically AWS firewall rules) for lambda allow outgoing traffic but it might be changed in your case?

Comment: Is your function in a VPC?

Comment: Default memory and execution time/Timeout settings please

Comment: @Ludo21South It think I can't run the code locally..as for the security group, does outgoing traffic mean oubound rules? type,protocol,port,they are all set "all".

Comment: @Marcin yes,in a VPC.

Comment: @lloyd  128MB, 1 minute

Answer (score 2):

A very likely reason why your **lambda** timeouts is because it is in VPC. As such it has **no internet access** since it does not have public IP. From [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-vpc.html):

> Connect your function to private subnets to access private resources. If your function needs internet access, use NAT. Connecting a function to a public subnet **does not give it internet access or a public IP address**.

To rectify the issue, the following **should be checked**:

- is lambda in a private subnet?
- is there a NAT gateway/instance in a public subnet?
- are route tables correctly configured from private subnet to the NAT device to enable internet access?

Alternatively, you may consider not putting it in a VPC in the first place if it is not required.